# 'HttpResponseForbidden' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an api for our users. I've decided to use `Django-rest-framework`.

Users need only GET requests. Each GET request has to have 'token' attribute to determine which data should we return.

So I've created a function which tries to get `user` object from `request` object.

```
def get_user(request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    if not token:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    user = get_object_or_404(User,auth_token=token)
    return user
```

I want to use this function in my view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def products(request):
    user = get_user(request)
    products = user.products.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

The problem is that when I doesn't provide `token` attribute, it raises:

> AttributeError at /api/products/
>
> Exception Value:  'HttpResponseForbidden' object has no attribute 'products'

Instead of proper response.

I can do:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def products(request):
    user_or_response = get_user(request)
    if user_or_response.__class__ != User:
        return _or_response
    products = _or_response.products.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

As you can see, it doesn't automatically return forbidden response, instead, it returns it as user. I can return it in `products` view but maybe there is a better way to do this with `Django-rest-framework`.

What should I do? Do you have a better approach or any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the `HttpResponseForbidden` is returned into your function, not from the view.

In this situation, you can try the following approach

```
def get_user(request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    if not token:
        return False
    user = get_object_or_404(User,auth_token=token)
    return user

@api_view(['GET'])
def products(request):

    user = get_user(request)
    if not user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    products = user.products.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

You can also potentially raise the exception instead of returning it in `get_user` and then handle it with a `try/except` inside the view.

Either way, it's just a little cleaner than comparing `.__class__` to `User`.

Answer (score 1):

So, right now it looks like you're muddling the difference between your model and your view. The model is the thing that looks up data. It generally should not be returning response code or handling validation with errors.

Python's behavior is correct, however. You are returning an object from `get_user` and then you are telling it to expect a products property on the returned object.

If I were you, I would do this:

```
def get_user(request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    if not token:
        return
    user = get_object_or_404(User,auth_token=token)
    return user


@api_view(['GET'])
def products(request):
    user = get_user(request)
    if not user:
        return HttpForbiddenResponse()
    products = user.products.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

I would *NOT* check the class. Not only does this not fair very well in Pythonic philosophy, but it also means that you can't do something like create an `AdminUser(User)` class. If you really want to return an arbitrary value from `get_user`, then I would do:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def products(request):
    user = get_user(request)
    if not hasattr(user, 'products'):
        return HttpForbiddenResponse()
```

That will check for a defined property, which matches OOP and a slightly more Pythonic approach.